# What is the use of heartbeat in stomp protocol?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

Currently I am using stomp protocol to send messages to activeMQ and to listen to messages. This is done in Nodejs using stompit library.

When the application is having high CPU or Memory usage, it stops sending heartbeat to broker. So the broker redelivers the message which is currently being processed, leading to repetitive processing of the same message

On disabling heartbeat, the application seems to work fine but I am unsure of the further issues disabling heartbeat might cause. Even when the broker is stopped while sending messages, behaviour seems to be same with or without heartbeat

I have read that it is an optional parameter but I am unable to find out it's exact use cases

Can anyone mention scenarios where no heart beat can cause issues to the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the purpose of heart-beating the [STOMP 1.2 specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Heart-beating) just says:

> Heart-beating can optionally be used to test the healthiness of the underlying TCP connection and to make sure that the remote end is alive and kicking.

Heart-beats potentially flow both from the client to the server and from the server to the client so the "remote end" referenced in the spec here could be the client or the server.

For the server, heart-beating is useful to ensure that server-side resources are cleaned up in a timely manner to avoid excessive strain. Server-side resources are maintained for all client connections and it helps the broker to be able to detect quickly when those connections fail (i.e. heart-beats aren't received) so it can clean up those resources. If heart-beating is disabled then it's possible that a dead connection would not be detected and the server would have to maintain its resources for that dead connection in vain.

For a client, heart-beating is useful to avoid message loss when performing asynchronous sends. Messages are often sent asynchronously by clients (i.e. fire and forget). If there was no mechanism to detect connection loss the client could continue sending messages async on a dead connection. Those messages would be lost since they would never reach the broker. Heart-beating mitigates this situation.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the detailed answer. But how do I prevent redelivery of messages when the application crashes, this leads to repetitive processing.

Comment: In order to prevent redelivery it's critical to understand exactly why it's happening in the first place. I recommend you create a new question for this so you can provide all the details.

Comment: Hi Justin, I have a doubt on this issue, If server heart beating is disabled and a dead connection won't be detected in such a case . 
How does the broker show consumers as 0 when the nodeJs server consuming to the queue is stopped?.